# Alt + Keys in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a single lined richtextbox and i want to add chars.
The chars will have 2 states. So the text in rtb will have some characters with red color and some with green.

It's possible when the user presses Alt+some character the character to be added to rtb in red color?.

Thank you

Comment: No, Alt+key keystrokes are not translated according to the keyboard layout.  Nor is it appropriate, they are shortcut keys to operate a menu or button.  A two radio buttons that let the user select the color.

Answer (score 1):

Yah!it's possible. Add one button and change the text name to &+.add code to the button and hide it. So if you will press the Alt + then the character to be added to rtb will be in red color.

Adding "&" before the exact name of the button or menu will allow you to press the button or menu.